# Geopandas - color based on populations in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

i have the following shape file for the united states, [file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/21e5bc0f82a76ff053de40950d958c3f20190913170133/34b832).

and the following dataframe with state names and populations
[image]

i tried plotting the shapefile and color it based on the populations of each state using the code below:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot 

fname = "states.json"

us = gpd.read_file(fname)

geoplot.choropleth(
    us, hue=population_mean['POPEST2016_CIV'],
    cmap='Blues', figsize=(8, 4)
)
```

but, i don't seem to get the correct colors. for example, highest populations have the darkest shade.

sample output:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

i solved it through merging

```
fname = "states.json"
us = gpd.read_file(fname)

us = pd.merge(us, population_mean, on=['STATE_NAME'])
us
gplt.choropleth(
    us, hue=us['POPEST2016_CIV'], projection=geoplot.crs.AlbersEqualArea(),
    edgecolor='black', linewidth=1,
    cmap='Greens', legend=True, legend_kwargs={'loc': 'lower left'},
    scheme='fisher_jenks',

)
```